# If $|\,f^{''}(x)| \leq M$ in $[a,b]$, then $\big|\,f(b)-f(a)-\frac{b-a}{2}\big(\,f'(a)+f'(b)\big) \big| \leq \frac{(b-a)^2}{2}M$

Tags: calculus

If$f^{''}$ is defined on $[a,b]$ and if $|f^{''}(x)| \leq M \forall x \in [a,b]$ then prove that $|f(b)-f(a)-\frac{b-a}{2}(f'(a)+f'(b)) | \leq \frac{(b-a)^2}{2}M$

My attempt
By taylor's theorem,
$f(b)=f(a)+(b-a)f'(a)+\frac{(b-a)^2}{2} f^{''}(\zeta)  , \forall\zeta \in (a,b),$ [as second derivative is bounded third and higher derivatives = 0, since $-M\leq{f^{''}(x)} \leq M$, Differentiating again $0 \leq {f^{'''}(x)} \leq 0$]

Putting this in above given problem,

$|\frac{b-a}{2}(f'(a)-f'(b))+\frac{(b-a)^2}{2} f^{''}(\zeta)| = |\frac{b-a}{2}(f'(a)-(f'(a)+(b-a)f^{''}(\eta))+\frac{(b-a)^2}{2} f^{''}(\zeta)|=|-\frac{(b-a)^2}{2} f^{''}(\eta)+\frac{(b-a)^2}{2} f^{''}(\zeta)|\leq (b-a)^2 M$

But in problem it is given as $\frac{M}{2}$. can you tell where i went wrong? On face of it, it looks ok to me

Comment: Inequalities  aren't  preserved when you differentiate. This would imply that every positive differentiable function is increasing for example.

Comment: can u pls elaborate ? i did not understand. I am just a novice in this area.

Comment: It looks like you've  tried to 'differentiate the inequality' $m \le f \le M $ to obtain $0\le f'   \le 0$. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: can u pls explain the reason? i got tht it does not make sense. But how

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x $ from $[0,1] $ to itself. We have that $0 \le f \le 1$ but what is the derivative of $f $?

Comment: yes, got it ... thnx ...

Comment: But i remember integration on inequalities ... Pls correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left|f(b)-f(a)-\dfrac{b-a}{2}(f'(a)+f'(b))\right|&=\left|f'(\xi)(b-a)-\dfrac{b-a}{2}(f'(a)+f'(b))\right|\\
&=\left|\dfrac{b-a}{2}(f'(\xi)-f'(a))+\dfrac{b-a}{2}(f'(\xi)-f(b))\right|\\
&\leq\dfrac{b-a}{2}|f''(\alpha)||\xi-a|+\dfrac{b-a}{2}|f''(\beta)||b-\xi|\\
&\leq\dfrac{b-a}{2}\left(M(\xi-a)+M(b-\xi)\right)\\
&=\dfrac{(b-a)^{2}}{2}\cdot M,
\end{align*}
where $\xi\in(a,b)$, $\alpha\in(a,\xi)$, $\beta\in(\xi,b)$.

Comment: this is cool, thnx

Answer (score 1):

By [Taylor Remainder Theorem in integral form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder), 
$$f (x)=f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x (x-t)f''(t)dt.$$ 
If $x=b$ and $x_0=a$ then 
$$f(b)=f (a)+(b-a)f'(a)+\int_a^b (b-t)f''(t)\,dt.$$
If $x=a$ and $x_0=b$ then 
$$f(a)=f (b)+(a-b)f'(b)+\int_b^a (a-t)f''(t)\,dt.$$
Hence, by subtracting the two equations above, we get
$$2(f(b)-f (a))=(b-a)(f'(a)+f'(b))+(b-a)\int_a^b f''(t)\,dt$$
and 
$$\left|f(b)-f(a)-\frac{b-a}{2}(f'(a)+f'(b))\right| \leq \frac{(b-a)}{2}\int_a^b |f''(t)|\,dt\leq\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}M.$$

Comment: can u pls tell me how did u write 2nd euation. Here b>a right? so f(b) = some function of a rigt? ....okkkkk got it ... thnx ... learnt that taylor's form can be expressed in integral form also. THank You Sir!

Comment: The general formula is $f (x)=f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x (x-t)f''(t)dt$ and we use it first with $x=b$ and $x_0=a$ and then $x=a$ and $x_0=b$.